# nuxt build --spa vs nuxt generate

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

What is the difference between

```
nuxt build
```

vs

```
nuxt generate
```

vs

```
nuxt build --spa
```

I am trying to compile three different variations:

```
1. regular nuxt with ssr
2. prerendered spa
3. spa without prerendering
```

I am struggling to find the appropriate commands for it

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As shown in [the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands), the above commands correspond to:

> `nuxt build`: Build your application with webpack and minify the JS & CSS (for production).
>   `nuxt generate`: Build the application and generate every route as a HTML file (used for static hosting).

The `--spa` flag doesn't seem to be covered in the docs themselves, however [the generator help](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/bin/nuxt-generate#L34) outlines, without further explanation:

> Options
>   `--spa` Launch in SPA mode

---

Given this information, it would seem the following commands should cover your needs, however I haven't tested them myself at the moment:

1. Regular Nuxt with SSR: `nuxt build`
2. Prerendered SPA: `nuxt generate`
3. SPA without prerendering: `nuxt build --spa`

Take all of this with a grain of salt, however, as the Nuxt team [is notorious for having out-of-date documentation](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/754).

Comment: I just tried several combinations. Seems that 1 and 3 are correct. But 2 (nuxt generate --spa) seems to produce the same output in the dist folder as 3 (nuxt build --spa). So generate needs to be used without the --spa flag to prerender the pages. Please update your answer and I will accept it

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the feedback, I've made the update.

Comment: Does `nuxt generate` also minify JS/CSS?

Comment: @AliGajani have you found answer I also have the same question or hint about minify JS/CSS

Comment: @A.L not sure about before, but `nuxt generate` totally allows dynamic routes nowadays.

Comment: in nuxt.config.ts add "ssr: false, target: 'static' ", and then use nuxt generate

Comment: What if you have different route rules? For example, prerender: true for blogs and landing pages and ssr: false for my dashboard. Should I use nuxt generate or nuxt build?